# IOS app size 100MB warning

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've uploaded my app to the itunes connect and am using TestFlight before I release my app. When i check my build it gives me a warning about the "Universal" Device type being over the 100 mb mark for the app to be downloaded over a network connection. All the rest are around the 60MB mark.[image]

I tested on my device, iphone 6 running 9.2.1. and in testflight it shows the app as being the correct size. But on another device iphone 6 running 8.2 it displays the Univeral size 149 and actually downloads it as that size. I don't why firstly the universal size is twice the size and secondly why is the iphone 6 running 8.2 downloading the Universal app.

[image: Correct Install Size]

Sorry i don't currently have a screen shot of the other device. but it has 149MB as the size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) to me:

> Note: Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later;
>   otherwise, the store delivers universal apps to customers.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, I think iTunes is responsible for making a general compiled causing a large increase in the size of the IPA. You can read more here.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17903